# Android SDK ping has encountered

Tags: android, eclipse

While starting on eclipse I am getting below message:

Android SDK ping has encountered a problem,
ping usageServer failed

OnClick on details:

pingUsageServer failed
Bad version: 22.0.5

I know this question is already posted, but I didn't find any relevant solution for this. I am using windows 8.

While running the SDK:

////////////////////////////////////////////
Fetching http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
Validate XML: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml
XML verification failed for http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml.
Line -१:-१, Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
Done loading packages.
Fetching http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
Validate XML: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml
XML verification failed for http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml.
Line -१:-१, Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
Done loading packages.

Comment: Finally I solved the issue by updating hosts file.C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc, in last line I updated  74.125.237.1 dl-ssl.google.com, and second this change the windows language Hindi to english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue by updating hosts file.C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc, in last line I updated 74.125.237.1 dl-ssl.google.com, and second thing I change the windows language Hindi to english.

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly because when you have other languages installed in parallel to English.

For correcting this issue go to: *control panel* > *language* > *Advance Settings*. Set *Override for Windows display language* to *English*. Do the same for *Override for default input method* and then restart Eclipse.