# Android Development Tools

Tags: android, eclipse

I've installed the Android SDK on my Dell Inspiron 1525. However,whenever I write the code and hit run, I get a dialog box saying "**Your Project contains error(s).Please fix them before running your application**" even when neither my .java file nor my .xml file shows any errors.On opening Eclipse I get a dialog box saying "'**Android SDK ping' has encountered a problem. PingUsageServer failed.**". Is the popping up of the dialog box(regarding SDK ping) causing problem when I'm running my code?....

Comment: In eclipse there is a window at the bottom called "Problems" and often times errors will show up there that sometimes wont pop up in code (often has to do with build files, gen files, etc.) check that and see if it gives you any more information

Comment: i hope this might help you [Android SDK ping has encountered][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584948/android-sdk-ping-has-encountered

Comment: I clicked the "Details" option when the "PingUsageServer failed" dialog box popped up;It says"Bad Version 22.2.9"...And I did open the "problems" window you mentioned.The error which is shown there is "Error generating final archive: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13 Unknown Android Packaging Problem". I did  try cleaning the project but to no use.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when importing. Right click on the project and go to properties and in the Android tab, make sure you have an Android version selected and in the Java Build Path tab, and make sure all your libraries are present.